# Induction proof [ little-o notation ]

Tags: induction

I have to prove that $ 2^n = o(n!) $, that is, $ \forall c \gt 0 \quad \exists$ $ n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $ \forall n \ge n_0$ we have $ 2^n \lt c.n! $

Well, this is what I did so far:

First I proved, by induction in $n$, that $ 2^n \lt c.n! $ (considering $c = 1$ and $ n_0 = 4$).

Then I proved, by induction in $c$, that $ 2^n \lt c.n! $ (considering $c \gt 1$ and $ n_0 = 4$).

Now I got stuck trying to prove for $0 \lt c \lt 1$. (I tried to consider $c$ as $\frac1m $ and prove by induction for $m \gt 1$)

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Induction does not work for reals ($c$ in your case) only integers ($n$ in your case).

Comment: Thanks. I thought that proving for c and then proving for c+1 would prove for all c (real) in that interval.

Comment: No, induction only proves for integers. Think about it - if you prove $P_1$ and also that $P_n \implies P_{n+1}$ then together they imply $P_2$ and then $P_3, P_4, \ldots$. But nowhere did we prove $P_\pi$ or $P_{1.5}$, for example

Answer (score 3):

Sufficient to check $2^n/n!\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Observe that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n/n!=e^2$, so the series $2^n/n!$ converges uniformly. Thats it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to prove without using series concepts?

Comment: I think that's what you got.

Comment: yes. define $a_n=2^n/n!$, and look at $a_{n+1}/a_n$.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but could you please explain a little bit more? Step by step if possible.

Comment: What didn't you understand?

Comment: How to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty} (2^n/n!) = 0$. I'm not used to the properties that you used.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to look at this problem. We can write
$$
\frac{2^n}{n!} = \frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{2}{n-1}\cdot\frac{2}{n-2}\cdots\frac{2}{3}\right)\cdot\frac{2}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{1}
$$
Now each factor in the parenthesized part is strictly less than $1$ so we have
$$
\frac{2^n}{n!} < \frac{2}{n}\cdot\frac{2}{1}= \frac{4}{n}
$$
Let $c>0$ be an arbitrary real. For that $c$ we'll have $4/n < c$ if and only if $n>(4/c)$ so we can take $\lceil4/c\rceil + 1$ to be your $n_0$ and we're done, having satisfied the conditions of the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks! But if we consider $n \gt 4/c$ we can't consider our $n_0$ as $\lceil 4/c \rceil$ because the statement says that $n \ge n_0 $, so $n$ may be equal to $n_0$. For example, choosing $c = 2$ our $n_0$ would be $\lceil 4/2 \rceil = 2$, and the statement $2^2 \lt 2 . 2!$ would be false. Am I wrong?

Comment: Good catch. Fixed.